# Sum of array in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How could get the sum of an array in python, if array contains multiple variables ? How do we use sum function? Is the map function useful for that purpose ?

Where as cardinalities are variables that I got from the internet.

```
t = (cardinality_x, cardinality_y, cardinality_z)

Sum = map(sum, t)
print(Sum)
```

Comment: What is `cardinality_x` etc? Why not `sum(t)`?

Comment: Please add example of `t` and expected result.

Answer (score 4):

try `total = sum(t)`. You do not need map.

Comment: This answer seems perfect considering the lack of any other details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a for loop through it. Like so:

```
{t = (3, 5, 1)
total = 0
for number in t:
    total = total+number

print(total)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import array
from functools import reduce
from operator import add


arr = array.array('i',[1,2,3,4,5,6,73,76]) 


# method 1
result = 0

for ele in arr:
    result += ele

print("sum is", result)



# method 2 

result = sum(arr)

print("sum is", result)



# method 3 ( from python 3.8 ) (not recommended)
total = 0
[total := total + x for x in arr]

print("sum is", total)



# method 4

total1 = reduce(lambda x,y : x + y,arr)

print("sum is", total1)



# method 5

total2 = reduce(add,arr)

print("sum is", total2)
```